# Заполнить массив неизвестным количеством чисел

Tags: c++, c

Как заполнить массив неизвестным заранее количеством чисел?
Пользователь просто вводит с клавиатуры 2 или 100000 чисел и они все должны быть внесены в массив.

Comment: Используйте `std::vector`, и будет вам счастье. На C придётся вручную, через `realloc`.

Comment: Используй динамический массив

Comment: @MajorMeow, и как не указывать размер?

Comment: @VladD, можно поподробней про вектор?

Comment: @OleksandrZakrevskiy: Ну, объявляете пустой `vector<int>` и добавляете очередной элемент при помощи `push_back`. Размер при этом изменяется автоматически.

Answer (score 2):

На самом деле лучше использовать vector. Вот пример:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator> // заголовочный файл итераторов
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> array1; // создаем пустой вектор
    // добавляем в конец вектора array1 элементы 4, 3, 1
    array1.insert(array1.end(), 4);
    array1.insert(array1.end(), 3);
    array1.insert(array1.end(), 1);
    // вывод на экран элементов вектора
    copy( array1.begin(),   // итератор начала массива
          array1.end(),     // итератор конца массива
          ostream_iterator<int>(cout," ")   //итератор потока вывода
        );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вы заранее указали 10 элементов.

Comment: Исправил. Лучше?)

Comment: а чем insert лучше чем push_back ? последнее вроде бы читабельнее.

Comment: @pavel Согласен, читабельнее. Надо было написать несколько вариантов добавления элемента.

Comment: А за что минус-то?

Comment: @VladD до правки я создал вектор, но не показал возможности добавления новых элементов. Наверное за это.

Comment: @VladD как вариант - за убогий insert, вряд ли за отсутствие <algorithm>.

Comment: @alexolut: Ну, для того, чтобы от минуса была реальная польза, нужно озвучивать проблемы в комментариях. Или писать альтернативный ответ.

Comment: @VladD это можно было бы легко реализовать в движке. Но это никогда не будет реализовано.

Comment: @alexolut: Но вы можете это исправить лично ведь? Дать полезный комментарий или альтернативный ответ. (Например: чем плох `insert`?)

Comment: @VladD я не минусовал, а про insert уже сказано было до меня. Так что мне нечего исправлять, при всем желании.